# Forward declaration of nested enum

Tags: c++, enums, nested, forward-declaration

I have code similar to the following:

```
class B
{
}

class A
{
  enum {
     EOne,
     ETwo
  } EMyEnum;

  B myB;
}
```

I want to declare a member of type EMyEnum in class B (which is declared before A).  Is this possible?  I realise the solution is to declare class B second, but for clarity I would prefer not to.

Comment: superset http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951234/forward-declaration-of-nested-types-classes-in-c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible... but it can be faked with inheritance abuse :)

```
namespace detail
{
  class A_EMyEnum
  {
  public:
    enum {
       EOne,
       ETwo
    } EMyEnum;

  protected:
    A_EMyEnum() {}
    A_EMyEnum(const A_EMyEnum&) {}
    A_EMyEnum& operator=(const A_EMyEnum&) { return *this; }
    ~A_EMyEnum() {}
  }; // class A_EMyEnum
} // namespace detail

class B { // use detail::A_EMyEnum };

class A: public detail::A_EMyEnum
{

  B mB;
};
```

On the other hand... why don't you simply forward declare B ?

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
  enum EMyEnum {};

  A();
  A(const A&);
  A& operator=(const A&);
  ~A();
  void swap(A&);

private:
  B* mB;
};

class B { // use A::EMyEnum };
```

Sure you need to actually write all the normally "default generated" methods of A, but hey that does not cost so much!

Comment: Yeah, the latter was what I ended up doing.  Just needed to confirm that my preference wasn't possible:)

Comment: What does `enum {} EMyEnum` mean? I've never come across it before?

Comment: @Olumide: It contains two weird nits inherited from C. First, in C you can immediately instantiate a `struct` or `enum`: `struct X { int x; } myX;` declares a variable `myX` of type `X`. Second, in C you can leave off the `struct` or `enum` name and thus create an anonymous type. It is often used on `enum` to declare constants in C: `enum { CONSTANT_A = 12, CONSTANT_B = 42 };` but can also be combined with the first nit to create a variable of an anonymous type. Obviously, in the particular context of this question, this is probably not what is intended...

Answer (score 2):

The current C++ standard does not allow forward declarations of `enum`s, although they will be coming in the upcoming C++0x standard.

See [here](http://www.devx.com/cplus/Article/42478/1954) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare A as template paramater of B.
Second way to solve it is using int - it is known that c++ enum is int.

Comment: It is only known in C, in current C++, every integer type might be emitted by the compiler.

Comment: @phresnel you are right, but I mean that it anyway could be casted to int