# Using an enum from a Forward Declared Class

Tags: c++, enums

**Current Problem:**

I need to access an **enum from a class that is forward declared**, similar to this situation:

**Human.h**

```cpp
#include "Dog.h"
class Human{
public:
  enum Language: uint32_t {
    None = 0,
    English = 1,
    Japanese= 2,
  };
}
```

**Dog.h**

```cpp
class Human;

class Dog{
   void understand(Human::Language speech);
}
```

**Dog.cxx**

```cpp
#include "Dog.h"
#include "Human.h"

void Dog::understand(Human::Language speech) {  
   // Do stuff with Human::Language
   return;
}
```

**Errors:**

- The IDE tells me Dog.cxx's implementation is not compatible with Dog.h's deceleration, citing the enum as `<erro-type>` in the error hint (only red squiggle)
- When compiling, any mention of the enum in Dog.h/c.xx throws errors, not being able to find the enum

**Extra Info:**

- MSVC 15 2017
- Full architecture of program requires the enum to be accessible like this
- Forward Deceleration is mandatory in order to solve a circular dependency within my program that is not seen here

Comment: (1) Do you mean Human::Language instead of Dog::Language in the Dog class? (2) Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842006/c-forward-declaring-class-scoped-enumeration?

Comment: where is the definition of `Dog::Language` ? I can only see a definition of `Human::Language`

Comment: My apologies for the mistake, it has been fixed

Comment: Why does it need to be forward declared? Couldn't you just include the header? Perhaps we need more context.

Comment: Generally, you can't do anything with a forward declared class except declare a pointer to it.

Comment: The forward deceleration is mandatory since it resolves a circular dependency within my program that cannot be seen here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the answer is no, you can't forward declare the enum in this context. Your choices are:

1. Move the enum into a lightweight base class.

```cpp
struct HumanBase
{
  enum Language: uint32_t {
    None = 0,
    English = 1,
    Japanese= 2,
  };
};

//fwd declare
struct Human;
```

2. Move the enum out of the class.

```cpp
enum HumanLanguage : uint32_t {
  None = 0,
  English = 1,
  Japanese= 2,
};
struct Human;
```

and then if you need to later on, you can do:

```cpp
struct Human
{
  typedef HumanLanguage Language;
};
```

3. Change all the method that use the enum to be a template (which may work in some cases, possibly not in others)

```cpp
class Dog{
   template<typename LanguageType)
   void understand(LanguageType speech);
};
```

Comment: I found option 1 to be the simplest and most effective