# How to forward declare an enum that is defined within a class

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, forward-declaration

According to [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2764.pdf), you can forward declare an enum. But what happens if the class or struct that the enum was declared in wasn't defined?  What's the recourse then?

I've also gone through the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71416/forward-declaring-an-enum-in-c), and it doesn't answer this question.

Example:

File *A1.h*

```
struct A1 {
  enum E1 { x1, y1, z1 };
  void fn1(A1::E1& e);
  void fn1(A2::E2& e);
};
```

File *A2.h*

```
struct A2 {
  enum E2 { x2, y2, z2 };
  void fn2(A1::E1& e);
  void fn2(A2::E2& e);
};
```

Comment: You mean, analogous to [forward-declaring nested classes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951234/420683)?

Comment: Gah! Yes. This still hasn't been fixed!? :(

Comment: As far as I know, no. Maybe there's an alternative solution to your problem? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Unless something is used only by the class, put it outside the class to prevent issues such as this. You can put the class and and associated supporting definitions in a namespace.

Comment: @NeilKirk It is actually used inside.  I didn't show that. Updated example to reflect that.

Comment: @Adrian, I think you misunderstand Neil Kirk, he said unless something is only used by the class.  Meaning if you use it elsewhere, you probably should put it outside of the class.  You can assign it to an appropriate namespace though.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity, I see. I guess that's an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forward declaration of nested enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238170/forward-declaration-of-nested-enum)