# Forward declaration of nested struct

Tags: c++, inner-classes, forward-declaration

Consider this situation:

```
struct Foo
{
    struct Bar
    {
    };
};
```

How do I forward-declare `Foo::Bar`?

---

What I tried:

```
struct Foo::Bar;
```

> error: 'Foo' has not been declared

```
struct Foo;
struct Foo::Bar;
```

> error: 'Bar' in 'struct Foo' does not name a type

```
namespace Foo
{
    struct Bar;
}
// ...
struct Foo
{
    struct Bar
    {
    };
};
```

> error: 'struct Foo' redeclared as different kind of symbol

```
struct Foo
{
    struct Bar;
};
// ...
struct Foo
{
    struct Bar
    {
    };
};
```

> error: redefinition of 'struct Foo'

Comment: `struct Foo { struct Bar; };` then `struct Foo::Bar { ... };`

Comment: @BoPersson of course you can forward declare a nested type, which is not the topic of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951234/forward-declaration-of-nested-types-classes-in-c

Comment: @BoPersson [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872728/forward-declaration-of-a-nested-class) is actually an exact duplicate of this question

Comment: @BeyelerStudios - One problem with `struct Foo { struct Bar; };` is that although you have forward declared `Bar`, you have also fully declared `Foo` without any other members. I can't see that this is useful very often, or preferred over `namespace Foo { struct Bar; };`

Comment: @BoPersson this is very common in the PIMPL idiom (and yes, you have to fully specify `Foo`)

Comment: @Ivan can you specify your usecase?