# C++ code fails to compile after upgrading XCode 5.0 -> 5.1 "forward declaration of class cannot have a nested name specifier"

Tags: xcode, xcode5.1

I have this in a .h file:

`class Ogre::ManualObject;`

I don't know how it got there but it's always compiled under multiple compilers - until suddenly XCode5.1 raises it as an error.

Have Apple changed the C++ compiler *again*?

Comment: And was this really ever legal C++?

Comment: What is the exact error? I am no C++ Standard expert, but the draft version from January 2012 explicitly mentions *forward declarations* as a valid tool. And the XCode 5.1 release notes also provide no other information.

Comment: The error is in the title. It's specifically because I forward declare a class inside a namespace instead of `namespace Ogre{ class ManualObject; }`

Comment: @John Add the fix to an answer, works for me.

Answer (score 3):

As John suggested, change `class Ogre::ManualObject;` to `namespace Ogre{ class ManualObject;}`. I had exactly the same problem (but with different declarations), also with Ogre and Xcode 5.1. Changed 3 lines, everything worked.

Comment: I don't think that would work if you also had
`class Ogre;`, e.g.:

`class Ogre;
namespace Ogre { class ManualObject; };`

gives me with clang++-11 `error: redefinition of 'Ogre' as different kind of symbol`

Answer (score 0):

Possibly that never was legal. It would depend on the code around it (hard to say just based on that one line without knowing the referencing points). See this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951234/1947205).

Apparently, you are not the only one experiencing this issue after an XCode 5.1 update. See this thread regarding [Scaleform (autodesk.com)](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Scaleform-Mobile-Development/Building-with-Xcode-5-1/m-p/4882182). I however couldn't find anything related in the XCode or LLVM/clang release notes.