# Can I use a type in a forward declared class?

Tags: c++

This class has an enum:

```
class ThreadController
{
public:
  enum ThreadType { ... }
}
```

Is it possible to use `ThreadType &` from the forward declared class?

```
class ThreadController;

class ThreadWorker
{
public:
  static ThreadWorker makeThreadWorker(const ThreadController::ThreadType & type);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
'ThreadType' in 'class ThreadController' does not name a type
```

But since I am using a reference, can't the compiler be happy with not having a definition in the header file?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know anything about what `ThreadController` contains at that point.

Comment: How do you tell the compiler? A nice use of `typename`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forward declaration of nested types/classes in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951234/forward-declaration-of-nested-types-classes-in-c)

Comment: @MiyazawaKenji, It needs the definition. It can't possibly gather anything from just a declaration.

Comment: I thought it didn't need a definition since the reference type is just an 8-byte pointer (on x86-64).

Comment: @chris That's a language limitation though - "can't possibly" is taking it too far. Allowing forward declarations of nested entities would be one possible way around it, for example.

Comment: Can you reverse the two? Forward declare `ThreadWorker` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `makeThreadWorker` a templated function.

```
template <typename T = ThreadController>
static ThreadWorker makeThreadWorker(const typename T::ThreadType & type)
{

}
```

The compiler will throw an error if `T` doesn't contain `ThreadType`. Optionally add a `static_assert` to restrict `T` to `ThreadController` only.

```
static_assert(std::is_same<ThreadController, T>::value, "error");
```