# Forward declaration within class in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a question about forward declaration in C++

```
class Outer::Inner; // not valid. error
class Outer {
    Inner * inn; // not valid, needs forward declaration.
    class Inner {
    }
}
```

But when implemented like this:

```
// class Outer::Inner; // not valid. error
class Outer {
    class Inner; // forward-"like" declaration within class
    Inner * inn;
    class Inner {
    }
}
```

Compiles ok. But I have never seen implementations like this before (because of my small experience in C++), so I'm interested in knowing if this won't cause some kind of error or unpredictable behaviour in the future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forward declaration of nested types/classes in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951234/forward-declaration-of-nested-types-classes-in-c)

Comment: I believe you can also write `class Inner * inn;` to combine the forward declaration with the pointer declaration.

Comment: I think it's not a duplicate. The OP apparently does not want to use the `Outer::Inner` syntax but wonders if a forward declaration of a nested class is allowed in the first place.

Comment: @rlbond No, that does a very different thing.

Comment: Ah yeah, it seems to declare a class `B` that isn't in the scope of `A`. Unfortunate.

Comment: Also note that since class `Inner` is declared in `Outer` it has access to its `private` parts which can be very useful to move implementation details into it (see the PImpl idiom and https://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2011/12/17/who-has-access-to-your-private-parts/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's valid. The standard says:

> **9.7 Nested class declarations** `[class.nest]`
>
> If class `X` is defined in a namespace scope, a nested class `Y` may be
>   declared in class `X` and later defined in the definition of class `X`
>   (...).

The following example is given, too:

> ```
> class E {
>   class I1; // forward declaration of nested class
>   class I2;
>   class I1 { }; // definition of nested class
>   };
> class E::I2 { };
> ```

Source: [C++11 draft n3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)

`E` and `I1` correspond to `Outer` and `Inner` in your question.