# Why is it allowed to deduce a private type?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, private, template-argument-deduction

Triggered by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54468330/how-to-properly-declare-a-subclass-c/54468592?noredirect=1#comment95745150_54468592) I was wondering if there is a legal hack to get an alias to a private nested type (note that the question was about something completely different and also this one is **not** "how can I access something declared as private?"). Inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8165847/4117728) my first step was to write this:

```
class foo {
    struct bar{};
    public: void foobar(const bar&){}
};

struct hack {
    template <typename T>
    operator T() { return {}; }
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    //f.foobar(foo::bar());// NOPE: bar is private !!
    f.foobar(hack());      // hm, bar is not private?
}
```

And I have to admit, I am already lost. **Why is it allowed to let a template deduce a private type?** Also considering that

```
struct no_hack {
    operator foo::bar(){ return {}; }
};
```

is not allowed (`foo::bar` is private).

Note that I am not asking what is the motivation behind allowing the `hack` but rather what parts of the standard can explain this difference? Is type deduction not restricted by `private`?

Comment: For why this is allowed, [cppreference notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access#In_detail): "The intent of this rule is that replacing any `private` with `public` never alters the behavior of the program." If switching from `private` to `public` added implicit conversions to be considered, then behavior could be changed; by having implicit conversions ignore access specifiers, this can't happen.

Comment: @ShadowRanger have to admit i cannot really follow you (its already late here ;). My conclusion after reading the dupe is that `bar` actually has to be considered as public because it appears in a public argument list.

Comment: One way to look at it is to see what would be lost if this was not allowed. If a class wants to return some kind of proxy-class (like `std::vector<bool>`s `operator[]` for example) the proxy-class would have to be public. This is obviously not ideal as it's an implementation detail that the user (usually) don't need to know or care about.

Comment: @super hm, implementation detail in the sense of: users dont **need to** care about, but even if the proxy is declared private, users of the class can easily create proxy objects if they want

Comment: @user463035818 Important destinction here is that users of the class can **use** the proxy, but they can't create it. Only the internals of the class can, and it can choose when and how it should be done.

Comment: @super depends on the details, in the example in this question I could easily create a `bar` and call methods on it (if it had any)

Comment: @user463035818 How would you create a `bar` in main in your example?

Comment: @super like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TcDfNL0DRSzn481w). Btw dont get me wrong, i am not trying to insist on anything. I know that `private` is largely a convention (a very useful one) and if you want you can break anything.

Comment: Again, I think there's an important distinction here between *easily create* and *going out of my way to create*. But you are right, at this point we're just nit-picking. Your example is not something that would just happen by accident.

Comment: @super the reason that i am picking that much is that before my state of knowledge was that, dirty hacks aside, `hello()` is not accesible, now I learned it is (even with not so dirty hacks). Maybe this is something obvious to others, but for me it was an eyeopener :)