# C++: Issues with circular dependencies

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

I currently have a situation with circular dependencies.  I have two classes, let's call them A and B:

```
#include <classB.h>
class A {
public:
    typedef Atype Sometype;

    MyReturnValue usefulFunction(B::Btype, ...)


};
```

And in class B, I have:

```
class B {
public:
    typedef Btype Someothertype;
};
```

And I need to add a method to B that takes a pointer to A::Atype, such as:

```
    CoolReturnValue doSomething(A::Atype *value, ...)
```

However, the compiler gives me an error regarding incomplete types.  Is there any "easy" way to get something like this to work?  Classes A and B are not simple classes.  I understand that I could probably get this to work by moving B::Btype and A::Atype into namespaces, and then creating class A and class B within those namespaces; however, that type of change would involve refactoring a codebase of several hundred thousand lines, which I don't have the bandwidth for at this time.

Comment: I apologize.  I meant circular dependencies.  There are no shared inheritance issues between classes A and B.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forward declaration of nested types/classes in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951234/forward-declaration-of-nested-types-classes-in-c)

Comment: I was afraid that was going to be the answer.  Now I really want to do a "git blame" to figure out who created this mess in the first place...