# C++ inherit template class with its own in-class struct

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance

```
template <typename Foo>
class A{

};

class B : A<B::Bar>{
    struct Bar{

    };
};
```

I wonder how could I do something like this, or it's the only way to move struct Bar outside the class B.

Comment: you could have `class B : A<X> { using Bar = X; }` in case you insist on having `B::Bar` (of course you'd need to supply the actual definition as `X`)

Answer (score 3):

You simply can't do it!

You can not use an unknown type as template parameter and you can't forward a nested class type. Both together makes it impossible to do what you like to do.

About forwarding a nested class declaration see here: [forward declaration of nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951234/forward-declaration-of-nested-types-classes-in-c)

There was already a proposal to add such thing to C++, but I think it is not part of the standard even not in C++20. [Forward declarations of nested classes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0289r0.pdf)