# Include nested class in C++ public header

Tags: c++

I have a public header that has class X. X has a private member of nested type U::V. As I understand, normally, you just forward declare the types but I cant forward declare nested type. U::V is in a private header so I cannot #include them from a public header. What do I do to have X know of class U::V?
Summary of my code:

```
// in include/mylib/box.h
class X {
 public:
  X();
  //...
 private:
  U::V stuffs; // how do I have this declaration work?
};

// in some private file
class U {
  class V{
  // ..
  };
};
```

Comment: What distinction are you making between “public” and “private” headers? Why do you feel you can’t include one from the other?

Comment: Incidentally, you can’t have a member variable of a forward-declared type, regardless of whether it’s a nested type.

Comment: You might be looking for [pimpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972588/is-the-pimpl-idiom-really-used-in-practice)

Comment: I had one suggestion that the pimpl idiom might help, I can just put U::V in a  pimpl class. I feel like it's applying a whole idiom for a small problem. Is there a simpler or better solution?

Comment: ahh, thanks, guys,

Comment: A nested type is a member of the enclosing class. In general you cannot declare class members without having the class defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized this happens because I got an incomplete class definition, not because it's a nested class. Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

> What do I do to have X know of class U::V?

Only way to have a member of type `U::V` in `X` is to define the type `U::V` before defining `X`.

You can avoid storing the member directly by using the [PIMPL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) idiom. In short, you would store a pointer to a forward-declared type.

Comment: I made a class that can help with PIMPL. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/090c0d4c5d0ab42a

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered by Adam Rosenfield [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/951245/7807082).

> You'll have to un-nest at least one of the nested classes