# What to do when an enum name clashes with a class name?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I have an enum Pitch and a class Pitch, both naturally to me should be named as such, however it's confusing to have both with the same name. Are there any guidelines for when an enum's name clashes with a class type?

EXAMPLE:

```
public enum Pitch
{
    Fastball,
    Sinker,
    Curveball
}

public class Pitch
{
}
```

Comment: If you have two types that you want to name the same, there is probably a problem with your design. Can you show us the code for the class and the enum?

Comment: Doesn't seem like anybody answered how to deal with an Enum with same name as clash - when the source code comes from someone else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Name the enum PitchType, PitchKind, PitchMagnitude, PitchQuality, PitchShape, PitchSpeed, PitchStrength or whatever fits best.

---

Another consideration is whether the class design could be improved. Instead of having a PitchType property inside the class Pitch, you could also create a class hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Pitch {}

public class Fastball : Pitch {}

public class Sinker : Pitch {}

public class Curveball : Pitch {}
```

Comment: How about PitchType? Can anyone think of a better word than Type though, since that has a meaning within the runtime itself?

Comment: public enum Pitch { Fastball, Curveball, Sinker }

Comment: Other names for the enum: ActionPitch, EventPitch

Answer (score 4):

Embed the enum in the class:

```
public class Pitch
{
    public enum Kind {
        Fastball, 
        Curveball, 
        Sinker
    }
}
```

You can then access it through the class:

```
Pitch.Kind.Fastball
```

Comment: I thought of that, but does that violate some convention of OO that I can't think of? Does making one go through the extra level of naming just to deal with a clash mean it's still good design?

Comment: I see no problems here. But the enum should preferably be embedded in the class in which it will be used or at least it should have a strong logical relation to it.

Comment: See stackoverflow question [Pros and cons of using nested C++ classes and enumerations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216748/pros-and-cons-of-using-nested-c-classes-and-enumerations).

Answer (score 3):

Use namespaces to group them logically. For the framework the class name is the full name, which may be `MusicPlayer.Notes.Pitch` and no just `Pitch`. Classes in different name spaces thus cannot clash.

Comment: the using statement would beg to differ.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott: The `using` statement is about deterministic resource management, are you confusing it with the `using` *directive*? In that case, you'd just have to fully qualify the type names when used if you end up `using` both namespaces. And if you're aliasing a type to an already existing name, well, that's your problem entirely.

Comment: Thank you for the correction - the using _directive_ is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

When an enum is not embedded in a class make sure you use some different name before the label so as to prevent name clashes. You can also use namespaces  as suggested by joey.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Pitch
{
    public enum Enum {
        Fastball, 
        Curveball, 
        Sinker
    }
}
```

`Pitch.Enum.Fastball`

Answer (score 0):

In the immediate instance where the enum is actually the identifier for the class, I settled on nesting the enum inside the class and naming it with the name: Option.  I named the Option property: Id.

```
public class Pitch
{
    public Option Id { get; set; }

    public enum Option
    {
        Invalid = 0,
        Fastball = 1,
        Sinker = 2,
        Curveball = 3
    }
}
```